# Nest LI functions

Tags: jquery, html, function

I've basically got this markup:

```
<div class="navBar">
  <div class="inner blueTheme"> 
    <ul id="" class="navBarMenu">
      <li class="xenonActiveMenu blue"><a href="/new_order">Orders</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="backBtn"><a href="#">&lt; Back</a>
          </li>
          <li class="xenonActiveMenu "><a href="/new_order">New Order</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>  
      <li class="green"><a href="/account_details">Profile</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="backBtn"><a href="#">Back</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.navBar .inner ul > li').bind('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    item = $(this);
    if (item.attr('class') != 'selected' && item.attr('class') !='backBtn') {
        item.addClass('selected');
        var parent = item.parent();
        var barWidth = item.width();
        var hasSub = item.find('ul').length;
        if (hasSub > 0 ){
        //Item Does have a submenu
        parent.children().each(function(){
            $(this).animate({marginLeft: -barWidth}, 400);
        });
        }
    } else {
        var parent = $(this).parent().closest('li');
        var barWidth = $(this).width();
        parent.each(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginLeft: barWidth}, 400);
        });
    }
    });
```

My Problem is, that it thinks the "li" element has been clicked twice, becuase there's two separate functions for nested LI elements, I just don't know a way around it, can anyone help?

Shannon

Comment: May be you should cancel the bubble event to avoid the event to be run twice. if (event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); } (for firefox and webkit) and event.cancelBubble = true; (for IE)

Comment: @user1073122 jQuery will handle the normalization for [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on jQuery-wrapped event objects. You should submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), which does exactly what its name suggests: it prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree to the next level of `<li>` elements.

Alternatively, you could separate your handlers to make the code a little more readable, using `$('.navBar .inner > ul > li')` for the first level, and `$('.navBar .inner > ul > li ul li')` for the second.

The updated code using `stopPropagation` is shown below.

```
$('.navBar .inner ul > li').click( function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // your code for handler
});
```